# tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: atScrollPosition: animated: with a text to find in textLabel.text

Tags: uitableview

I have a tableView connected to coreData. Is it possible to use the method tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: atScrollPosition: animated: so that the tableView scrolls to the correspondent row that has a specific string in textLabel.text?

In alternative, i can store, the indexPath. But without that?

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is very achievable, and can be done with a simple for() loop logic search:

```
- (int) indexForSearchTerm:(NSString *) searchTerm {

for (int i=0; i < [dataSource count]; i++) {
    NSString *temp = [dataSource objectAtIndex:i]
    if ([temp isEqualToString:searchTerm]) {
        int selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
return selectedIndex;
}
```

And to use this method, you would simply call:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self indexForSearchTerm:@"whatever word you're looking for"] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```